# a sequence of numbers chosen from 1 to 9

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

> How many sequences $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ satisfy $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < x_5$ if $x_i$ is chosen from {1,2,3,...,9}?

This question is quite intimidating, but for any 5 numbers you choose from the set, there has to be only one way to order them such that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < x_5$, so I just did $\binom{9}{5}$ - is that correct? Or are there other ways of solving it?

Comment: Yes, I think this is fine. An ordered five tuple corresponds to a specific choice of numbers.

Comment: Totally correct, and there should be no easier solution. Since the order is fixed, the number of sequences is just the number of possible choices $5$ out of $9$.